# Restlet & MULTIPART_FORM_DATA or another way to put files on Google App Engine via Restlet

Tags: java, file, google-app-engine, rest, restlet

I tried to receive files via restlet but only gets the complete MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.
How can I extract my specific file?

I found some code-blocks but the types of them are not available...
[RESTlet: How to process multipart/form-data requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996819/restlet-how-to-process-multipart-form-data-requests)

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
factory.setSizeThreshold(1000240);

// 2/ Create a new file upload handler
RestletFileUpload upload = new RestletFileUpload(factory);
```

**My current code:**

```
@Put
public void handleUpload(Representation entity) {
    if (entity !=null) {
        if (MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA.equals(entity.getMediaType(), true)) {
            Request restletRequest = getRequest();
            Response restletResponse = getResponse();
            HttpServletRequest servletRequest = ServletUtils.getRequest(restletRequest);
            HttpServletResponse servletResponse = ServletUtils.getResponse(restletResponse);

            try {
                Upload2(restletRequest, entity);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

public void Upload2(Request req, Representation entity) throws IOException
{
    ...
        GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance());
        ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel)); 
        copy(entity.getStream(), oout);
        oout.close();
```

After storing with this method I have something like that and I only want to store the content with the name "picture":

```
��z------WebKitFormBoundarysOvzWKPqyqW7DiTu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename="_MG_4369.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

����*ExifII*
```

As far as I read parsing of multipart form data isn’t supported yet? But there must be a solution to send files via restlet

I tried the rest-calls via postman for chrome. The is only on multiparts the support for files. Is a possible solution to send the image as a raw-text?

Comment: I can't find a matching java client side code. Can someone provide a matching java client side code/link? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add `Exception` handling and deal with the `InputStream` and potentially clean up of temp files (see `DiskFileItemFactory` docs)  but the basics are as follows, when using the org.restlet.ext.fileupload library.

```
@Put
public void handleUpload(Representation entity) {
    List<FileItem> items = new RestletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory())
                 .parseRepresentation(representation);
    for (FileItem item : items) {
        if (!item.isFormField()) {
            MediaType type = MediaType.valueOf(item.getContentType());
            InputStream inputStream = item.getInputStream();
        }
    }
}
```

for a gae Solution try replacing the `DiskFileItemFactory` with a `gwtupload.server.MemoryFileItemFactory`.

Comment: that looks like the right way but items is empty. on gae I'm not allowed to create local files. maybe that's why items is empty? I tied `DefaultFileItemFactory` but still no items

Comment: To be fair I have never tried it on `gae` but both the `Default` and `Disk` versions of the `FileItemFactory` do try to create temp files, in the System temp directory so I suspect that this is the issue.

Comment: How about trying a `gwtupload.server.MemoryFileItemFactory`?

Comment: that looks quite good! I think thats it but I test this solution later that day and give a response

Comment: Okay I tried it but there is any problem. The uploaded file is broken. But that looks like another problem

Comment: @Chloe do you have a reference to the 'org.restlet.ext.fileupload' extension module/package?

Answer (score 0):

You should send your file uploads as an `InputStream`.  Then you can use this:

```
@Put
public void handleUpload(InputStream entity) {
}
```

The file is now its stream and will no longer have form data inside of it.  To send a file as a stream, you can set up a client in java (using jersey, for example).

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

File f = new File("C:/file/to/upload.zip");
InputStream data = new FileInputStream(f);
Client client = Client.create();
client.setChunkedEncodingSize(1024);
WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:80/your/uri");
ClientResponse response = resource.accept("application/x-octet-stream").type("application/x-octet-stream").post(ClientResponse.class, data);
```

Now that you have `data`, you can set up a client to post `data` to your server.  I was trying this using multipart form data and postman before.  I went mad trying to get multipart data to work.  But this is the solution I have been using instead.  And it works perfectly.

Comment: And how is this working with Restlet and any other "Client"? Java, Objective C, .net, vbs and so on? The idea behind rest is the platform   autonomy

Comment: Not sure, but if you don't want answers in java, don't use the java tag

Comment: I use the java tag because the rest is written with restlet and java. But the rest has to be accessible via rest-conform methods. Example curl or others like I said

Comment: Not all of your Restful methods, get, post, put, and delete are stuck using this new jersey client stuff.  Only the one using file upload.  The others can use their existing representations

Comment: Sorry but I don't see a solution for my problem. This looks like another way to send files but has nothing to do with restlet?!?

Comment: Your question states "or another way".  The client I posted will send a POST request to your server.  Your server using rest can accept the POST sent by the client.

Comment: At the end of the day, this client is constructing an HTTP POST message.  It's as standard as it gets.