# Sending a Multipart request to a restlet web serivce

Tags: java, rest, restlet, multipartform-data

I was trying to send a Multipart post request to a restlet based web service, and then I stumble upon this link.
http://restlet.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4447&dsMessageId=2401065

It says that its possible to parse a Multipart request with Restlet 1.1 or 2.x but there is no provision for sending a multipart/form data.

Comment: does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996819/restlet-how-to-process-multipart-form-data-requests

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example. I went through it, but it only tells about processing(consuming) a multipart/request which has actually come from a form. I wanted a solution to create a multipart request from a file on the file system or forward a multipart request recieved by controller to a rest service.

Comment: For now what I did was convert the file received by my controller to a Base 64 encoded string and sent it to the rest service as a normal post request. This accounts for a 30% increase in file size which will account for a significant network hit and and overhead of encoding and decoding, which is why I was looking for an alternative.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  I haven't done this myself, but I believe the [FormDataSet](http://restlet.org/learn/javadocs/2.2/jse/ext/org/restlet/ext/html/FormDataSet.html) class may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161517/restlet-multipart-form-data-or-another-way-to-put-files-on-google-app-engine-v/18191022