# Reading Mutipart Form in Camel and Standalone Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, jetty, apache-camel, mime, multipart

I have a web application running in tomcat 7 and leveraging camel. The client posts a form with multipart form data. Pretty much similar to what is done here:

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/branches/camel-2.11.x/components/camel-jetty/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/jetty/MultiPartFormWithCustomFilterTest.java

The question is, without camel-jetty, how can I read the multipart files in my route? 
It appears that everything ends up in the body of the message. I do not want to manually parse this multipart content.

Or alternately, is there a way to use camel-jetty but without starting the jetty server? 
My web app is already running in a web container and there is no point in starting jetty.

I tried to implement a custom binding and apache commons FileUpload to read these attachments. I retrieve the servlet request getBody(HttpServletRequest.class). However, parseRequest ends up throwing null pointer exception because apparently content type is null.

Comment: Might be easier to goto a servlet container using Servlet API 3.1 and use the spec provided [HttpServletRequest.getParts()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts()) and [@MultipartConfig](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html) features

Comment: This worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996819/restlet-how-to-process-multipart-form-data-requests.